# How to optimize the thruster direction on a rocket with infinite fuel.

Tags: calculus, vectors, mathematical-physics

So suppose we have a rocket that can produce a finite acceleration $a$ in any direction.  Given the rocket's current position $\mathbf p$ and velocity $\mathbf v$, we want to know what direction to point the thruster at the current time in order to reach the origin at velocity $0$ as quickly as possible.  I already know that when $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf p$ are linearly dependent, the solution is accelerate towards the destination until your speed reaches some critical speed where you would be unable to stop in time.  At this point, you decelerate for the remainder of the trip.  My question is what happens in the general case when you have some tangential velocity that needs to be cancelled out.

Comment: Not math!!!!!!!!!